# How to remove updates not in WSUS

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-7, group-policy, wsus

Good morning everyone.

I have a weird issue here.  I am new to the IT Admin role but every computer we have purchased new since I started is getting the windows 10 notification pop up.  I run windows updates before putting it on the domain so it has not linked up to WSUS at the time.  My questions are:

1. Is there a way to remove the updates from the computer if they are not in WSUS or do I need to go to every computer?
2. I made sure the computers are communicating with the GPO on the server and Notifications for next version of windows is off yet it is still showing.  Any idea why?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Jim B that the 'correct' way to do this is using the "*Turn off the upgrade to the latest version of Windows through Windows Update*" Group Policy Setting, however I have had limited success with this as have many others. (Well documented when looking on Google)

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/charlesa_us/2015/06/25/how-to-remove-block-and-prevent-get-windows-10-application-for-enterprise-environments/ - Suggests three alternative methods. In your case I would probably suggest using method two;

Create a new Registry Key under "*HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows*" called "*GWX*" and a new DWORD value called "*DisableGWX*" with a value of 1

You could of course deploy this as part of your base build as part of a Task Sequence or however you're doing it, or you could use Group Policy Preferences if you need to target existing machines.

UPDATE: You'll also need to ensure your Windows 7 systems are running KB3065987 to support disabling this 'feature'.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to disable the upgrade in the enterprise is to enable the "Turn off the upgrade to the latest version of Windows through Windows Update" policy that was released. This would of course presume your systems are fully patched.